# Why does google maps fail when run through IP

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a dev environment on an ip address `http://10.0.0.15/lrbc`, and maps throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function VM19375:120` when I click to move the map.  It loads fine, just can't drag the map because it error on `mousedown` or `dragstart` ( i can't tell its minified )

The same exact page, when run through `http://apps01/lrbc` works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<script>
  window.mapsCallbacks = [];
  window.mapsInit = function(){
    console.log('init');
    mapProp = {
      draggable: true,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
      zoom: 8,
      streetViewControl: false,
      clickable: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    };
    var m = document.getElementById('aaa');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(m, mapProp)
  };
</script>

<div id="aaa" style="height: 300px; width: 300px"></div>

<div class="content-steps"></div>
<div class="content-forms">
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="/lrbc/images/loading.gif" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-actions"></div>
</body></html>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=mapsInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's fine, i can use the dns mapped `apps01` address, but this took like an hour of poking and prodding until I stumbled upon what was going on.  So my question is why is this happening?

Comment: just kidding, now I'm getting the error on `apps01` as well.  This is so annoying with no reasonable means to debugging I am thinking about switching to bing.

Comment: o.. m...g... it breaks when I have `console` open in the browser.. WHAT?  Does this have anything to do with the react developer tools, which I installed at home and somehow appeared on my work chrome as well.

Comment: so... my console was spoofing a user agent setting.. which must have gotten automatically set at some point because it was a string and I don't remember pasting in a fake user agent... WEIRD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

As I said in comments to the original post:

- This issue was caused when console.log was open
- This was from a network user agent spoof that was causing chrome to pretend like it was firefox.  I just reset the user-agent stuff and it works again.

That being said, proprietary minified code is a pain to debug.  I wish there was a great open source maps solution